# How to make join in django

Tags: django, join, django-queryset

I have next models:

```
class User(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)


class UserMarketSubscription(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    market = models.ForeignKey('Market', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_in = models.DateField(default=year_back)
    date_out = models.DateField(default=year_back)

class Market(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Shortly to say, I have User that can be subscripted on several markets.

At the end I want to get QuerySet that contains all users and their information about subscription(1 user per row). So i want to get nearely next field_names('id', 'market1_date_in', 'market1_date_out', 'market2_date_in' ..., 'marketN_date_out)

I have tried annotations, but it does not work since, it requires exact field name on annotation, and i can't do it in cylce over each Market.

'values_list' method returns many objects of one user with different subscription details, I want all details in one object.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use select_related and prefetch_related in queryset

[see the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#select-related)

Comment: prefetch_related can be useful for me. But it only prefetchs list of related objects, and don't build needed structure, shown in question. I need exact structure for further excel export.

Answer (score 0):

You can try for:

```
user_obj.usermarketsubscription_set()
```

Comment: It only returns list of related set, the point is that, I don't know how to get all the data in one query in different fields.